# Unable to printf long long int

Tags: riscv

I am printing values to a buffer using:

```
int j = 2;
float k = 1.2f;
double l = 0.6;
long long int m = 0x7fffffffffffffff;

char buffer[100] = { 0 };

char *pc = buffer;

usart_init();

sprintf(buffer, "%d %p %.20f %.20f %lld\r\n", j, pc, k, l, m);
```

The compiler issues no warning, but the long long int is not printed in the buffer. The RISC-V compiler is set up for RV32I and ILP32. What may be the cause? Do I need to add specific options to the C compiler?

Comment: Have you tried it on [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/) for cross verification?

Comment: Well. it seems the my compiler is not set up for sprintfing long long, because all I see is "ld" (and no number), so it looks like it doesn't understand "%lld".